# How to configure oozie workflow for multi-input path with multiple mappers

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie

Can any one help me in configuring a work flow with Map-Reduce action, that takes multiple input paths each input path is associated to one Mapper as like MultipleInputs.addInputPath api takes input path and a mapper. The out put of these mappers will be given to reducer.

I tried this with java action, but it will execute only one map task. But here input path contains huge data, so java action will not us in this case.

Is there any way in handling this case?

Regards,
Krish.

Comment: Have you got a driver class that launches this map reduce job already (in developing / testing your job)? If so, look at the job.xml generated, you should be able to see what configuration was, and configure the oozie map-reduce action accordingly.

Comment: I could see job.xml file that is generated, I will try with these configurations and will update here on the same.

Comment: its working for me, sorry for late reply.

Comment: GHK, can you share the solition that works in your case?

Comment: Create a work flow with below properties (for each property add your value based on your input and output), <property>
<name>mapred.input.dir.mappers</name>   <value>INPUT_PATH1;com.xxx.SampleMapReduceJob$FirstMapper,INPUT_PATH2;com.xxx.SampleMapReduceJob$SecondMapper</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.input.dir.formats</name>
<value>INPUT_PATH1;org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat,INPUT_PATH2;org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat</value> 
</property>

Answer (score 1):

In the workflow you can give a comma separated list of input directories in `mapred.input.dir` . This will make the files in those directories to run on different mappers.

Comment: Thay may depend the version used for me it was mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats and mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.mappers. To be sure I suggest Chris White's comment