# Multiple Input Paths configuration in OOZIE

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to configure a Mapreduce job in oozie . This job has two different input formats and two input data folders. I used this post [How to configure oozie workflow for multi-input path with multiple mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270454/how-to-configure-oozie-workflow-for-multi-input-path-with-multiple-mappers)
and added these properties to my workflow.xml :

```
        <property>
                <name>mapred.input.dir.formats</name>
                <value>folder/data/*;org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat\,data/*;org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat</value>
            </property>

            <property>
                <name>mapred.input.dir.mappers</name>
                <value>folder/data/*;....PublicMapper\,data/*;....PublicMapper</value>
            </property>
```

but when the job is launched i have the following error: " No input paths specified in job".

Is there anyone that can help me ?

thks

Comment: These look like (obfuscated) relative paths - do these paths exist for one user, but oozie runs the job as another user?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris.
The path are indeed relative path (the displayed above paths are not the real ones). The same path works well for a single input format and the mapred.output.dir property. It's seems that the properties given above are not taken into account by OOZIE and introduced in hadoop configuration.

Comment: So if you fully qualify the paths, does the oozie job run as expected?

Comment: With fully qualified paths,When MultiInputs and several InputFormat are used the oozie job fails. However, In one input format  case, when "classic" mapred.input.dir property is used, the oozie run normally.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set some additional properties:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingInputFormat</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today, so I used the following properties.

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingInputFormat</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats</name>
  <value>/first/input/path;org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat,/second/input/path;org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.mappers</name>
  <value>/first/input/path;com.first.Mapper,/second/input/path;com.second.Mapper</value>
</property>
```

The difference is instead of `mapred.input.dir.formats` and `mapred.input.dir.mappers` which is part of the old map-reduce API I used `mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats` and `mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.mappers` respectively. The code worked just fine after that. I ran it on Hadoop 1.2.1 and Oozie 3.3.2.