# Oozie processing input in multiple directories with one mapper

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm trying to set up an Oozie map-reduce workflow action to process inputs files spread across multiple directories. Concretely, say my input is spread in the following directories

```
/data/d_20150629-2200
/data/d_20150630-2210
/data/d_20150530-2220
/data/d_20150531-2230
/data/d_20150701-2240
/data/d_20150702-2250
```

In general there isn't a straightforward glob pattern to capture the list of files that I expect at runtime.

The input specification in my workflow.xml is:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
    <value>${inputFile}</value>
</property>
```

And the parameter value in my workflow.properties is:

```
inputFile=/user/streaming/data/d_*
```

With this, my Oozie job is naturally processing *all* directories under `data` that begin with `d_`. Is there a way to modify workflow.xml or workflow.properties to tell Oozie to process files under only the listed six directories?

In Pig, one can specify comma-separated list of input paths. I also came across these two posts ([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270454/how-to-configure-oozie-workflow-for-multi-input-path-with-multiple-mappers), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194472/multiple-input-paths-configuration-in-oozie)) which touch upon the issue. But in my case, I neither want to apply different mappers on different input paths not have different input formats. I just want to specify multiple input directories to the same mapper.

Hadoop version: Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.1.5
Oozie client build version: 4.0.0-cdh5.1.5

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapred.input.dir` documentation states that it's

> a comma separated list of input directories

So you could you define a property in workflow.properties

```
inputFilePath=/user/streaming/data
```

And use it in workflow.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
    <value>${inputFilePath}/d_20150629-2200,${inputFilePath}/d_20150630-2210, ...</value>
</property>
```

But if you want to run it only once, then it's easier to copy/move the needed to a separate directory and pass it to input.

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail. I was able to make this work without hardcoding in the `workflow.xml` file. The first option in [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-oozie-users/201203.mbox/%3CCAGjKHXAoE=1V26u46=rit=TRRG-p+TjABV9o4MhYEk9CYYFpiw@mail.gmail.com%3E) post helped me get it to work. But I've accepted your answer since it could work as well.