# Oozie mapred.input.dir.mappers doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, oozie, oozie-workflow

I'm trying to run Oozie (v4.3.0) flow, in one of my Jobs I have multiple inputs and multiple Mappers for each input. This is how it looks in Driver class:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, LeftMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, RightMapper.class);
```

But in Oozie workflow.xml it could look like, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270454/how-to-configure-oozie-workflow-for-multi-input-path-with-multiple-mappers) and [this](http://hadoopinrealworld.com/configuring-multipleinputs-inputformats-mappers-in-oozie-mapreduce-action/):

```
        <property>
            <name>mapred.input.dir.mappers</name>
            <value>
                ${left};com.pge.mapreduce.join.LeftMapper,${right};com.pge.mapreduce.join.RightMapper
            </value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>mapred.input.dir.formats</name>
            <value>
                ${left};org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat,${right};org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
            </value>
        </property>
```

But this doesn't work for me, I'm getting error

> No input paths specified in job

**UPD**

`job.properties`:

```
nameNode=maprfs:///
jobTracker=maprfs:///
queueName=default
examplesRoot=demo-flow
userName=mapr    
left=${nameNode}/user/${userName}/${examplesRoot}/left.csv
right=${nameNode}/user/${userName}/${examplesRoot}/right.csv
```

Comment: Those `mapred` properties are deprecated https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html

Comment: @cricket_007, Right, thank you, but I'm still getting the same error:(

Comment: It's not clear where `left` or `right` are defined or how `args` is passed into the Java action

Comment: @cricket_007, updated.
All props are in job.properties. In logs I can see that 
`mapred.input.dir.mappers` and `mapred.input.dir.formats` are properly set

Comment: Still not sure where `new Path(args[0])` gets assigned to anything. Can you show the full Java Oozie action?